# How to escape comma in csv perl

Tags: perl, csv

In my csv file there are thousands of records.And those records contain data with comma.How i should escape .I seen few links which mentioned about using module
TEXT::CSV.But still issue persist ie recofds gets break where ever comma comes.
Here is sample code i have been working:

```
 use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
 my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get CSV file on the command line\n";
 use Text::CSV;
 my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ',' });
 my $file = 'Pkg_Notes_small.csv';
 my %data;
  my %dupes;
  open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

 while (my $line = <$data>) 
 {

  my $catalog_num ='';
  my $catalog_sid ='';
  my $note_text ='';
  my $packing_notes_id ='';
  #($catalog_num,$catalog_sid,$packing_notes_id,$note_text) = split ',', $line;
  if ($csv->parse($line)) 
  {
      my @fields = $csv->fields();
      $catalog_num = $fields[0];
      $catalog_sid = $fields[1];
      $packing_notes_id = $fields[2];
      $note_text = $fields[3];
     }
   }
```

i will add sample data from csv file :

```
CATALOG_NUM  CATALOG_SID    PACKAGING_NOTES_SID    PACKAGING_NOTES_DESC


112194  ,     521     ,        77      ,        For WI Packaging Operations: For 
                               finishing  operations, the  use of a protective
```

comma used above for clarity. Now converting this data to query based on my requirement for which i am getting:

for which **Notetext** field i am getting is :

```
    For WI Packaging Operations: For finishing operations
```

remaining part for this line after processing is missed out.the data iam expecting  is :

```
  For WI Packaging Operations: For 
  finishing  operations, the  use of a protective
```

Comment: Have a look at quotemeta http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html

Comment: Please, show a line that contains the problematic comma.

Comment: Input line : For WI Packaging Operations: For finishing operations, the use of a protective apron and nitrile gloves is mandatory.

Comment: output result : For WI Packaging Operations: For finishing operations

Comment: problematic field is : $note_text = $fields[3];

Comment: @ccheneson quotemeta does worked the way i wanted.

Comment: You should give us some sample data to work with.

Comment: That is not valid csv, as the comma is unquoted. Does it always occur in the last field on the line? Or what other means can you use to distinguish the line?

Comment: Also, is that a line break in the last field?

Comment: Does it really have all those spaces? Is this a file with fixed width fields?

Comment: i have putted comma just for seperation of data .CSV file will not have comma seperating with column.no file will not be having fixed width.

Comment: "No file will not be having fixed width"? Did you mean to say "All files will have fixed width"? Are you also saying that you manually put the commas in, and that the real data will not have commas? Please enter the **real** data you intend to process, exactly as it occurs. Use the code formatting option so we can see it.

Comment: I suspect he meant "no, file will not be fixed width". Damn those pesky commas :-)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to have commas in records in CSV files if the fields that contain them are quoted.

```
field1,field2,"field3, with embedded comma",field4
```

But Text::CSV knows all about that, so if you're using Text::CSV and still getting truncated records, then it seems likely that the problem is with your input data. If the embedded commas aren't quoted then obviously there is no way for the parser to differentiate between separator commas and commas that are part of the text.

```
field1,field2,field3, with embedded comma,field4
```

In the example above, how can the computer possibly know that the third comma should be ignored?

If this is your problem and you can't get the input data fixed, then there is one possible workaround. If the extra commas only ever exist in the last field of a record, then you can use the little-known third parameter to `split()` to limit the number of fields created from a record.

So if your record looks like this:

```
field1,field2,field3,field4 with, embedded, commas
```

You can use:

```
my @data = split /,/ $input, 4;
```

to force `split()` to only split the data into four fields. Anything after the third comma is all put into the fourth field.

Usually it's a very bad idea to parse CSV data using `split()` (because it doesn't know to ignore quoted commas), but in controlled circumstances like this, it can work well.

**Update:** Now I have seen some (well, one line!) of your input data, I see that my prediction was right. You have unquoted commas in your data. So using Text::CSV is not going to work.

But my `split()` solution works fine. Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
  my @fields = split /,/, $_, 4;
  say $fields[3];
}

__END__
112194 , 521 , 77 , For WI Packaging Operations: For finishing operations, the use of a protective
```

And the output I get is:

```
For WI Packaging Operations: For finishing operations, the use of a protective
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to add in four or five complete lines of your input data (including one or two of the problematic ones).

Comment: If the last field has line breaks in it, like the sample implies, you cannot use this method.

Comment: Ah. It didn't look like a line break when I looked at it. No, that would complicate things massively :-/

Comment: It is possible to use the same method, include the `binary => 1` option, and join the 4th field after parsing. E.g. `$field[3] = join "", @field[3..$#field]`.

Comment: Yes u r right.It worked @DaveCross for me at last thanks for ur effort.but it was dirty to do so.but works thanks.i learned from it.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, then please consider accepting it.

Comment: i would love but dont have reputation enough